# Identifying which cell my UILongPressGestureRecognizer was pressed from, can not add a tag to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I add my UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a cell like so:

```
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2.5;
    longpressGesture.t
    [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];
    [longpressGesture release];
```

I want to know which cell the UILongPressGestureRecognizer was pressed in, I cant add a tag to it, is there some clever trick to do to find out this info?

Comment: You can subclass the UITableViewCell and add a variable that holds whatever information you are trying to get back from the tableviewcell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You added it to the cell so the cell is the recognizer's view:

```
- (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)gr.view;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Then all you need to do is get `indexPathForCell` and you have all the information you could possibly need